# Android studio old apps

Tags: android-studio

I found an old phone and tablet that i was using to develop Android apps on. The computer that had the codes for those apps was fried by lightening. It's there a way to pull the published apps of those devices to the new computer and continue to develop them in Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the [Android Decompiler](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) to get the source code from a compiled APK. If you were using Proguard you will still have some challenges in the names but as you have written the code you can simply replace the mangled names with correct one.